# Read more than one word from string with sscanf

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am trying to read formatted content from a file. To do so, I read line by line using `fgets()` and `sscanf()`.

The content of the file is supposed to be a table. One row would look like the following example:

```
456    2    39    chained_words    62.5    // comment with more than one word
```

To read it, I use:

```
fgets(temp,MAXLINELENGTH,file);
sscanf(temp,"%d %d %d %s %f // %s",&num1,&num2,&num3,word,&num4,comment);
```

It works fine with the first five elements plus the first word after the `//`, but the problem is that I need to store the whole comment in the `comment` char * variable. I have tried multiple solutions proposed in other posts, like specifying format that excludes certain characters, but nothing worked.

I'd appreciate any hint to solve the problem!

Comment: This is one of the many things proposed in other questions that didn't work for me.

Comment: `sscanf()` might not be the correct tool for the job.

Comment: That was a mistake writing the example, I apologize. I use `%f` in my program.
@GregHewgill, do you suggest any alternative?

Comment: In fact, in my program I try to read a number with comma, not point. So I scan for `%d,%d` and then process the input to obtain a float. But this is working fine, the only problem I have is with the comment.

Comment: Is `file` and `FILE *file` pointer?

Comment: Yes it is; declared `FILE *file` and opened for read only with `file = fopen("myfile.txt","r")`.

Comment: As long as chained words are truly chained, the `sscanf(temp,"%d %d %d %s %f // %[^\n]%*c",&num1,&num2,&num3,word,&num4,comment);` should do it. **note:** the `%*c` not 'technically' needed since `%d` will skip all whitespace, including `'\n'`, but it is a good habit to account for all chars in line.

Comment: Ok, now it's working! I can't understand why `%[^\n]` didn't work and `%[^\n]%*c` is working, but it is.

Comment: All `%*c` does is **read and discard** the trialing newline, which when reading from a new `temp` each time shouldn't matter, but if using `scanf` and reading from `stdin` you **must** have it to empty the input buffer (`stdin`).

Comment: Just one more question... What if the comment would be in the middle of the row, having, for example, another number after it? How could I delimit the scope of the string?

Comment: Then don't use `sscanf()` for that, it's for simple patterns, complicated patters would need more specialized code.

Comment: Then you have a couple of options. The easiest is to read with `fgets` (or `getline`), then use `strtol` to read the integers using the return of `endptr` to advance until the next char (or newline) is encountered, test whether next char is digit or text, if digit `strtol` again, if text, read using `fgetc` until next next char (digit, char or newline) -- repeat.

Comment: Are there any convenient features like 'at least two spaces between the last numeric field and the start of the words, and at least two spaces after the words and before the final numeric field'? Or tab separators instead of spaces? Or is there a column width for when the words start — and preferably end too? You could use `sscanf()` with `%n` to find where the words start: `if (sscanf(temp, "%d %d %d %n", &num1, &num2, &num3, &off) != 3) { …oops… } else { …words start at temp[off]… }`. You then have to decide how you know when you've finished reading words and are working on the final number.

Comment: There are tab separators between any pair of elements; between any 'column' of the table. There is no column width, although there is a max width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from your comment, if you were to add another number after the existing `comment`, that would complicate things a bit. The reason being is that with `comment` containing multiple words, you have no discrete end to search for.

However, C rarely lets you down. Whenever you need to parse data from a line or buffer, you look at the format of your data and ask "What am I going to use as my reference for the beginning or end of what I need?" Here, with nothing in comment, we will need to use the end of the buffer as a reference and work backwards.

Doing do we are going to assume that the value is the last thing on the line before the newline (no tabs or spaces follow). We could loop backwards until we find the last non-whitespace character to validate, but for purposes here we make our assumption.

For purposes of this problem, we will break parsing line into 2 parts. We can read everything up to the comment with our original `sscanf` call in a reliable fashion. So we will consider everything in the first part of a line (up to and including the float) part 1, and everything after the comment characters `//` part 2. You read/parse part one as usual:

```
        sscanf (line, "%d %d %d %s %f", &d1, &d2, &d3, word, &f1);
```

Searching for a specific character in a line, we have a manual char-by-char comparison (we always have that) and we have `strchr` and `strrchr` functions in `string.h` that will search a line of text for the first (`strchr`) or last (`strrchr`) occurrence of the given character. Both functions return a **pointer to that character** within the string.

Working backwards from the end of our line, if we find `/`, we now have a pointer (the address within the string) to the last `'/'` before the beginning of the comment. We now read the entire remainder of the line into `comment` (value and all) using our pointer.

```
        p = strrchr (line, '/');            /* find last '/' in line    */
        sscanf (p, "/ %[^\n]%*c", comment); /* read comment and value   */
```

Now we are working in only `comment` (instead of `line`). We know if we work backwards from the end of `comment` looking for a space `' '`, we will be in a position to read our last value. After we read the last value, since we have our pointer pointing to the address right before the value, we know we can `null-terminate` `comment` at the pointer to finish our parse.

```
        p = strrchr (comment, ' ');         /* find last space in file  */
        sscanf (p, " %d", &d4);             /* read last value into d4  */
        *p = 0;                             /* null-terminate comment   */
```

(**note:** you can check/removed any trailing spaces in `comment` if needed, but for our purposes, that is omitted)

Putting it all together you would have something that looked like this:

**Quick Example**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXS 128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {                /* check for at least 1 argument    */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input, usage: %s filename\n", 
                argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char line[MAXS] = {0};
    char word[MAXS] = {0};
    char comment[MAXS] = {0};
    char *p = NULL;
    size_t idx = 0;
    int d1, d2, d3, d4;
    float f1 = 0.0;
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    d1 = d2 = d3 = d4 = 0;

    if (!(fp = fopen (argv[1], "r"))) {  /* open/validate file   */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (line, MAXS, fp) != NULL)  /* read each line in file */
    {
        /* read buffer through first float */
        sscanf (line, "%d %d %d %s %f", &d1, &d2, &d3, word, &f1);

        p = strrchr (line, '/');            /* find last '/' in line    */
        sscanf (p, "/ %[^\n]%*c", comment); /* read comment and value   */
        p = strrchr (comment, ' ');         /* find last space in file  */
        sscanf (p, " %d", &d4);             /* read last value into d4  */
        *p = 0;                             /* null-terminate comment   */

        printf ("\nline : %zu\n\n %s\n", idx, line);
        printf ("   d1 : %d\n   d2 : %d\n   d3 : %d\n   d4 : %d\n   f1 : %.2f\n",
                d1, d2, d3, d4, f1);
        printf ("   chained : %s\n   comment : %s\n", word, comment);

        idx++;
    }

    fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
$ cat dat/strwcmt.txt
456    2    39    chained_words    62.5    // comment with more than one word    227
457    2    42    more_chained_w   64.5    // another comment    228
458 3 45 s_n_a_f_u 66.5 // this is still another comment 229
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/str_rd_mixed dat/strwcmt.txt

$ ./bin/str_rd_mixed dat/strwcmt.txt

line : 0

 456    2    39    chained_words    62.5    // comment with more than one word    227

   d1 : 456
   d2 : 2
   d3 : 39
   d4 : 227
   f1 : 62.50
   chained : chained_words
   comment : comment with more than one word

line : 1

 457    2    42    more_chained_w   64.5    // another comment    228

   d1 : 457
   d2 : 2
   d3 : 42
   d4 : 228
   f1 : 64.50
   chained : more_chained_w
   comment : another comment

line : 2

 458 3 45 s_n_a_f_u 66.5 // this is still another comment 229

   d1 : 458
   d2 : 3
   d3 : 45
   d4 : 229
   f1 : 66.50
   chained : s_n_a_f_u
   comment : this is still another comment
```

**Note:** There is no limit to the different ways to approach this. This is simply one approach. Another would be to **tokenize** the entire line into separate words, check whether each word begins with a digit (and contains a '.' for a float) and then simply convert all numbers and concatenate all non-number words as needed. It's up to you. The bigger your toolbox, the more ways you will see to approach it.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete answer, I've learned a lot! I'll start making some tests right now.